# Optional Type Parameters for a Class

Tags: c#

Suppose I would like to implement a generic class with four type
parameters:

```
class ExampleClass<TA, TB, TC, TD> 
{ }
```

The class will have many 'use cases' so it can happen that TA and TB are meaningless while only TC and TD are needed or the other way around. Is there an elegant way to make some of the type parameters optional?

Comment: I think maybe you're on the wrong track. What you actually need to accomplish? Maybe looking at the actual problem can give some strategy about how to solve the question.

Comment: The Class is implementing a Publish Subscribe functionality. What I want to do is to extend this class with Request Response pattern. And I wanted to keep everything in one base class.

Comment: In this case, I would try to do composition, and not inheritance. You have a class with 1 of two behaviours, or both. So I would say you need 2 base classes, one for each behaviour, and publish the two with a Facade. I can expand my answer if you need.

Answer (score 0):

No, unlike C++ templates, there is no "elegant" way; see [`System.Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) for the brute-force approach.  Note that client code often isn't that bad; `ExampleClass.Create(...)` instead of `new ExampleClass<T1, T2, T3>(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, it depends. I would probably try to encapsulate the use cases in some static factory methods, like the following:

```
public class Example<TA, TB, TC, TD> 
{
  public TA PropA { get; set; }
  public TB PropB { get; set; }
  public TC PropC { get; set; }
  public TD PropD { get; set; }

  public static Example<T1, T2, Object, Object> Case1Factory<T1, T2>(T1 a, T2 b)
  {
    return new Example<T1, T2, Object, Object>()
    {
      PropA = a,
      PropB = b
    };
  }

  public static Example<object, object, T3, T4> Case2Factory<T3, T4>(T3 c, T4 d)
  {
    return new Example<Object, Object, T3, T4>()
    {
      PropC = c,
      PropD = d
    };
  }
}
```

If you need to support more than 3 or 4 standard cases I would change approach.

Comment: One could combine this with type parameter constraints (base classes) to provide default behaviour, instead of using `Object` for the 'optional' type parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Type parameters just define the type for class members. If you use a type parameter in any member, those members require the type parameter and therefor it cannot be optional, but must at least be of type `Object`. Then you can decide to not use those members, but the class still requires the type.

The most elegant way for this scenario would be, to define base types for your 'optional' type parameters, because this way you can ignore members using unspecialized types as type parameters, since the base types provide no functionality when used as type parameters.

An example:

```
public class MyClass<A, B> where A : BaseA, B : BaseB {

    public A doSmth(B input)
    {
         return input.someMethod();
    }
}
```

For the implementations of BaseA and BaseB, nothing special should happen here, and therefor they can be used whenever you want them to be optional.